# Selected row GridView won't extract data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selected, selectedindexchanged

I have a GridView which I am filling with data from my database. The data displays perfectly. My problem is that I want to be able to click on a row and then display the information that is in that row elsewhere (eventually I'll have a splitscreen to format the selected data nicely). The selection works, because it highlights the current row. However, I cannot figure out how to display that data elsewhere. For now, I'm trying to display the content of a single cell in a label called testLabel. I've tried many different methods, and the testLabel never updates when I click a new row. Can anybody see what is going wrong here?

C#

```
protected void DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = DefaultGrid.SelectedRow;
    testLabel.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

ASPX

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID = "ScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id = "orderByLabel" Text = "Order By: " />


            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="orderByList" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="fName" Selected="True">First Name</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="lName">Last Name</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="state">State</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="zip">Zip Code</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="cwaSource">Source</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="cwaJoined">Date Joined</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="searchLabel" Text="Search For: " />
            <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" Columns="30" />
            <asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" />
        </div>
    <div align="center">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID = "up" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "orderByList"
        EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlId="searchButton" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="DefaultGrid" runat = "server" DataKeyNames = "fName"
        onselectedindexchanged = "DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged"
        autogenerateselectbutton = "true"
        selectedindex="0">
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Azure"
        forecolor="Black"
        font-bold="true" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Visible="false" />
        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>



    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="testLabel" Text="test" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, it should be working. Can you show the code that populate the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided own select button and also set property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateselectbutton.aspx to true. You must choose only one of those.

Edit: Ah, see it now. Label 'testLabel' is outside updatepanel. Move it to ContentTemplate.

Comment: Did you placed breakpoints in code? Is there a postback after selection? What is debugger saying?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing *testLabel* inside another UpdatePanel and force an update on it after you change the label's text?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it should be working. Here are a few pointers:

- When accessing `row.Cells[2].Text`, keep in mind the index is Zero based (first cell is indexed 0).
- You have a fixed column that is invisible. Although not showing, that column should count in your column indexing numbers.
- Place a breakpoint inside `DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged`. When it gets there, fool around with the possibilities by watching variables and calling methods. That should help you a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about the select button column? That one is definitely showing.

Comment: You have two of them defined, only one is showing. Look at @Tomas' comment on that

Comment: Also, did you place a breakpoint in `DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged`? Did it stop there? I suspect `DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged` is not being called. Remember that row selection coloring happens at client side, but your code in `DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged` happens in server side.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your `DefaultGrid_SelectedIndexChanged` ever get called. Check this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1448445.aspx

Quote:

> you need a buttonfield or a postback control such as a button, linkbutton,imagebutton with the commandName="Select" for the selectedIndexChanged event handler to trigger.

Comment: It does get called, as far as I can tell, because when I click on a new row, the color of that row changes.

Comment: Can you put a **breakpoint** in visual studio to justify that?